# Should I be linking these tables together?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not sure what to do for these 2 tables. One is a notes table at the "company" level.

However one of the fields is to specify which Employee you talked to. I am not sure if this Notes table should have reference back to the Employee or if it should just be a text field with their name in it.

```
NotesTable
id - pk
notes - nvarchar(max)
EmployeeId 
or
(EmployeeName) - nvarchar(200)

EmployeeTable
id - pk
firstname 
lastname
etc
```

The reason why I am not sure is if, I would put a hard delete(ie they can remove employees from their company). This relationship would be lost.

The only way around that would be to do a soft delete.

Is soft deletes the better way to go?

Comment: Yes, storage is cheap. Do soft deletes and set some sort of flag to inactive/terminated.

Comment: the notes table should have a link back to `EmployeeTable`.  This is what relational databases do . . . they support linking entities together.

Comment: Yea, that's why I am torn because I know it is probably what I should be doing but it gets weird when some records could be deleted and you don't really want those notes to disappear as well.

Comment: "Is soft deletes the better way to go?" - what does business say? Also remember european privacy laws regarding personal information which is something you do nto want to be ignorant of - can be expensive.

Comment: @TomTom - Well I have not made the case yet to them for this part, but I need to know the pros and cons of it, in the past they been fine with soft deletes though. with EU law, it is not a concern for us as 99% of the business comes from the North America(with probably like 95% USA)

Comment: Yeah, and the 5% cost you. Seriously. YOu can also mix - soft delete with hard delete after 90 days, that is where we move now for a customer. Gives a chance to undo.

Comment: To preserve your employee data, use an INSTEAD OF DELETE trigger, stopping the actual DELETE and instead updating the row(s) with your soft delete indicator.

Comment: Doing it by employee name is a really bad idea. What happens when a name is changed? Either soft deletes on the employee table, make the column a logical foreign key (not ideal) or set the EmployeeId to NULL in the Notes table when the Employee is deleted.